# Local datetime given address

Tags: python

How can I get the local datetime given the address therefore not what the local date time would be for my current location but what it would be for the given address. This should also take daylight saving into account.

Comment: Use some kind of map API (of which there are many) to convert address to coordinates and then use something like https://pypi.org/project/timezonefinder/ to find the local timezone by coordinates.

Comment: Question should be like , Date time zone format based on latitude and longitude

Answer (score 1):

If given the time zone of whatever address is in question, you can use Python's built-in modules `datetime` and `pytz`.

```py
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

tzone = pytz.timezone("US/Pacific")
today = tzone.localize(datetime.today())
today.strftime("%H:%M:%S") # => '16:58:59'
```